# include the word "table" in List of Tables, "Appendix" in Table of Contents, etc

Tags: latex

I need to include the word "Table" at the beginning of each line in my List of Tables. That is, instead of:

```
  LIST OF TABLES
 1   The first table   ........... 10
 2   The second table  ........... 20
```

I need it to say:

```
  LIST OF TABLES
 Table 1   The first table   ........... 10
 Table 2   The second table  ........... 20
```

Yes, I know that's ugly, but those are the rules.

I also need the Table of contents to say:

```
  Table of Contents
 1  The first Chapter             ...... 1

 Appendices

 Appendix A  The A appendix     ........  10
```

Any idea how to do this in a simple and consistent manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your three questions:

1: Table prefix in the list of tables put the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength\tablelen

\settowidth\tablelen{Table}

\addtolength\cfttabnumwidth{\tablelen}

\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table }
```

2: To have "Appendices" appear in your table of contents put the following just after your call to \appendix:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
```

3: To have "Appendix" as a prefix for each appendix in the table of contents, see:

http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/pgweb/thesisfiles/bhamthesisman.pdf
http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/pgweb/thesisfiles/bhamthesis.dtx

in particular, search for his `\renewcommand{\appendix}` in which add to contents is changed.

Answer (score 2):

The easier way is to replace the word `\listoftables` with

```
{%  
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%  
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%  
\listoftables%  
}
```

Comment: Hello. Is there a way to add `\quad` between the `table` and the `number` in `listoftable`?